# Kotlin Function Return Data Class Error, Type Mismatch, Required: <Data Class>#1

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have a data class of a sextuple.
My function is supposed to return a Sextuple.

For some reason, the code will not compile, complaining about a type mismatch.

I have other functions with similar setups--some return Pairs, some return generics--but they all work. I'm not sure why there's a problem with reading this type mismatch. I've tried to move things around to no avail.

```
data class Sextuple<out A, out B, out C, out D, out E, out F>(
        val first: A,
        val second: B,
        val third: C,
        val fourth: D,
        val fifth: E,
        val sixth: F
    )

private fun <Sextuple>update(buttonEvent: Int, toggle0: ToggleButton, toggle5: ToggleButton, toggle10: ToggleButton): Sextuple{

        //some code to create cout[] and w vals 

        //correctly infers String type
        val display0 = display0Switch(Pair(w18, cout[13]))

        //correctly infers String type
        val display5 = display10Switch(Pair(w18, cout[10]))

        //correctly infers String type
        val display10 = display5Switch(Pair(w18, cout[7]))

        //correctly infers Int type
        val value0 = value0Switch(Pair(w12, cout[4]))

        //correctly infers Int type
        val value5 = value10Switch(Pair(w13, cout[2]))

        //correctly infers Int type
        val value10 = value5Switch(Pair(w14, cout[0]))

        val updated = Sextuple(display0, display5, display10, value0, value5, value10)
        return updated
    }
```

Under `return updated` it gives the following error:

Type mismatch.
Required: Sextuple#1 (type parameter of com.example.myApp.MainActivity.update)
Expected:com.example.myApp.MainActivity.Sextuple

I'm not sure what the #1 means or why its creating a problem. 
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect, you need to specify the type of each value in angle brackets after `Sextuple`.

Change this:

`private fun <Sextuple>update([Your parameters]): Sextuple`

To this:

`private fun update([Your parameters]): Sextuple<String, String, String, Int, Int, Int>`